# shell function expansion in bitbake recipe

Tags: shell, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

So, I have a shell function in a bitbake recipe, that, just for the sake of an example, will look at the recipe name and see if it has a "native" substring in it.

```
# foo.bb

# function is within foo.bb but outside other tasks.
is_recipe_native() {
    local is_native="false"

    case "${PN}" in
        *native*)
            is_native="true"
            ;;
    esac

    echo "${is_native}"
}

# a shell task within foo.bb
do_some_task() {

    # here, shell expansion won't work, resulting in an empty string.
    local is_native="$(is_recipe_native)"
    bbnote "${is_native}" # logs an empty string
}
```

In this case, the value of is_native is an empty string (""). Shell expansion does not occur, or bitbake doesn't know what `${is_native}` is.

However, if I do this, shell expansion occurs:

```
## foo.bb

## a shell task within foo.bb
do_some_task() {

    ## a shell function defined within the task.

    is_recipe_native() {
        local is_native="false"

        case "${PN}" in
            *native*)
                is_native="true"
                ;;
        esac

        echo "${is_native}"
    }

    # here, shell expansion works.
    local is_native="$(is_recipe_native)"
    bbnote "${is_native}" # logs "true" or "false" as needed.
}
```

I understand the discrepancy happens because of the way the run._do_some_task script is finally generated.

But there's some boilerplate occurs here and there in some recipes I'm working on that I want to consolidate into functions I can call (and interpolate within variables.)

But the amount of boilerplate doesn't warrant the trouble of using python, either.

So, the question is (and I can't seem to find an answer in the Yocto manual): can I define a shell function inside a recipe, but outside of tasks, that I can invoke, in a shell task, within a string via shell expansion?

Thanks.

Comment: If you change all your `${is_native}` to `$is_native`, does it work better?

Comment: Looks like you are no longer interested in getting an answer. It may mean you found the answer yourself. If so, do you mind sharing it with us and posting it here?